# what is the inflate analogue in windows phone or Windows development?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

In android we use use UI inflator to inflate a UI component in another UI like a custom menu list.
I have created some cards UI and I want to change it according to some action like button hit or swipe its pretty simple in android.
So,how to do it in windows phone or in windows development.

Answer (score 0):

Try a ViewBox control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Alternatively, you can apply a transformation to any UI control by setting the RenderTransform property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform(v=vs.110).aspx, for example you can use a ScaleTransform